# Oracle: Check dml statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dml

I'm looking for a way with Pl/SQL to check if a statement, which is executed by 'Execute immediate', is a dml statement.

Comment: No way I know of. Basically, if you're using Execute Immediate, it's your job to know what is being run - i.e. you should never let it run arbitrary code supplied by a user or some other program in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There may a solution to check if the query string contains *"INSERT" or "UPDATE" or ...*

But I don't think that may be general and consistent solution.

What if the SQL is calling a package or stored procedure that may call DML or DLL?

I think you may rely on [BEFORE / AFTER DDL TRIGER](http://psoug.org/reference/ddl_trigger.html) or investigate on [`ora_sysevent`](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:267415465220) function

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check it by using SQL%ROWCOUNT. for example (a rough block, untested)

```
set serveroutput on
begin
execute immediate 'update tableA set fieldA=100';
if(SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0) then
dbms_output.put_line('DML');
end if;
end;
/
```

SQL%ROWCOUNT returns the number of rows affected by the most recent DML. So, if a statement executed by execute immediate is a DML statement and if that changed anything, then sql%rowcount will be greater than 0. otherwise, if it is a DDL, then using SQL%ROWCOUNT will most probably raise an exception (or it will equate to 0)

Comment: In case of some update query like "update someTable where a criterai that have no result ?" SQL%ROWCOUNT will be 0, so the detection of DDL will fail pal.